# Python find largest rectangle on matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 2D numpy.array matrix with labels from **0->n** for example:

```
[[0 6 6 6 6 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 5 6 6 6 6 6 0 0 0]
 [0 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 0 0]
 [0 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 0 0]
 [0 5 5 5 6 6 6 1 0 0]
 [0 5 5 5 4 4 6 1 0 0]
 [0 5 5 5 4 4 4 0 0 0]
 [0 5 5 4 4 4 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

For each label, I want to find 2 largest rectangles. I have a function to find 1 largest rectangle for a particular label called `def find_largest_rect()`. So how can I find the second one? Is there any suggestion?

Comment: `pop` that item and call `find_largest` again.

Comment: could you explain it more? I don't want to remove the 1st one and do the `find_largest` on the entire cells. I want to search on the same cells but with condition that the position of the 2nd rectangle is different from the 1s one. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Where are the labels?

Comment: labels are the number 0 1 2 3...n on the matrix

Comment: you could replace that matrix with a checkerboard of unused labels so that it becomes a bunch of size 1 rectangles and then call `find_largest_rect` again